# Can't connect to S3 buckets with periods in their name, when using Boto on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

We're getting a certificate error when trying to connect to our S3 bucket using Boto. Strangely, this only manifests itself when accessing a bucket with periods in its name WHILE running on Heroku.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection({our_s3_key}, {our_s3_secret})
bucket = conn.get_bucket('ourcompany.images')
```

Raises the following error:

> CertificateError: hostname 'ourcompany.images.s3.amazonaws.com'
>   doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'

But the same code works fine when run locally, and would also work on Heroku if the bucket name were 'ourcompany-images' instead of 'ourcompany.images'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the [relevant github issue](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836), add this to the configuration:

```
[s3]
calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat
```

Or, specify the `calling_format` while instantiating an [`S3Connection`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.connection.S3Connection):

```
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat

conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key, calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())
```

The code worked for you locally and didn't work on heroku, most likely, because of the different python versions used. I suspect you are using `2.7.9` runtime on heroku, which has [enabled certificate checks for stdlib http clients](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/).

Comment: for all who use the popular Django-Storages wrapper, this is accomplished via your app's settings.py as explained here: https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html and here: https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/issue/181/from-s3-import-callingformat-seems-broke

Comment: It's charitable to say that those links "explain" the issue! But Brad Bode's comment at https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/issues/181/from-s3-import-callingformat-seems-broke#comment-10134874 zeroed in on the issue for me.

Comment: In Python 3.5.0, also had to specify region for this to work with `conn = s3.connect_to_region('us-west-2', calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())`

Comment: for django-storages use: from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = OrdinaryCallingFormat()

Comment: is there a way to fix this for boto3?

Comment: @cyniphile what version of boto3 are you having the issue with?