# Listing all S3 Objects on a bucket named after a subdomain

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, knox-amazon-s3-client

I need a complete listing of all the objects in an s3 bucket with a particular prefix. I have tried using previously mentioned solutions using [boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337912/quick-way-to-list-all-files-in-amazon-s3-bucket) and [knox-copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437581/node-js-amazon-s3-how-to-iterate-through-all-files-in-a-bucket), however, my bucket is named after a domain (ex: cdn.mycompany.com) and I get the following error back from boto

```
ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'cdn.mycompany.com.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'
```

I get a similar error back from knox-copy. Both work just fine if I use a bucket name without periods. Is there a way around this?

Comment: [Here's the actual problem and solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652318/cant-connect-to-s3-buckets-with-periods-in-their-name-when-using-boto-on-herok)

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me with python 2.7.9 and 2.7.10.
I found 2 workarounds.

changeing python version to 2.7.8

or

add in ~/.boto file (create if none) the following

> [s3]
>
> calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat
>
> S3Connection.DefaultHost = ‘s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com’

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my listing using the AWS-CLI solution posted by Lyke here:
[Quick way to list all files in Amazon S3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337912/quick-way-to-list-all-files-in-amazon-s3-bucket)

I had previously avoided CLI because I thought it would only return 1000 objects. However, it succeeded in listing all 2000+ items in my bucket.