# How to access keys from buckets with periods (.) in their names using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

### Context

I am trying to get an encryption status for all of my buckets for a security report. However, since encryption is on a key level basis, I want to iterate through all of the keys and get a general encryption status. For example, "yes" is all keys are encrypted, "no" if none are encrypted, and "partially" is some are encrypted.
**I must use boto3 because there is a known issue with boto where the encryption status for each key always returns None. [See here.](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836)**

### Problem

I am trying to iterate over all the keys in each of my buckets using boto3. The following code works fine until it runs into buckets with names that contain periods, such as "my.test.bucket".

```
from boto3.session import Session

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=<ACCESS_KEY>,
                  aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET_KEY>,
                  aws_session_token=<TOKEN>)
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = s3_resource.Object(bucket.name, obj.key)
        # Do some stuff with the key...
```

When it hits a bucket with a period in the name, it throws this exception when `bucket.objects.all()` is called, telling me to send all requests to a specific endpoint. This endpoint can be found in the exception object that is thrown.

```
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 82, in __iter__
for page in self.pages():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 165, in pages
for page in pages:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 85, in __iter__
response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 157, in _make_request
return self._method(**current_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 310, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 395, in _make_api_call
raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (PermanentRedirect) when calling the ListObjects operation: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

### Things I have tried

- Setting the endpoint_url paramter to the bucket endpoint specified in the exception response like `s3_resource = session.resource('s3', endpoint_url='my.test.bucket.s3.amazonaws.com')`
- Specifying the region the bucket is located in like `s3_resource = session.resource('s3', region_name='eu-west-1')`

I believe the problem is similar to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652318/cant-connect-to-s3-buckets-with-periods-in-their-name-when-using-boto-on-herok) in boto, which fixes the problem by setting the calling_format parameter in the s3Connection constructor. Unfortunately, I can't use boto though (see above).

### Update

Here is what ended up working for me. It is not the most elegant approach, but it works =).

```
from boto3.session import Session

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=<ACCESS_KEY>,
                  aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET_KEY>,
                  aws_session_token=<TOKEN>)
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')

# First get all the bucket names
bucket_names = [bucket.name for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all()]


for bucket_name in bucket_names:
    # Check each name for a "." and use a different resource if needed
    if "." in bucket_name:
        region = session.client('s3').get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_name)['LocationConstraint']
        resource = session.resource('s3', region_name=region)
    else:
        resource = s3_resource
    bucket = resource.Bucket(bucket_name)

    # Continue as usual using this resource
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = resource.Object(bucket.name, obj.key)
        # Do some stuff with the key...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of [github](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/81) [issues](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/245) on this. It's related to the region of the bucket. Make sure that your S3 resource is in the same region as the bucket you've created.

FWIW you can determine the region programmatically like this:

```
s3.meta.client.get_bucket_location(Bucket='boto3.region')
```

Comment: Your method to programmatically get the bucket region saved the day! I ended up getting all the bucket names first using `bucket_names = [bucket.name for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all()]` (which works for all buckets) then checking each name to see if it contained a ".", using a region specific resource if needed. Thanks your your help!

Answer (score 6):

Just generalizing the great answer provided from [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430241/ben-whaley).

```
import boto3
knownBucket = 'some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

#get region
region = s3.meta.client.get_bucket_location(Bucket=knownBucket)['LocationConstraint']

#set region in resource
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',region_name=region)
```

Comment: Both answers are good. This helped me to get the correct region on my bucket in my python code.