# How to use boto3 to view contents of a path within a bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

The region seems important based on comments regarding issues with bucket names containing periods ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534410/how-to-access-keys-from-buckets-with-periods-in-their-names-using-boto3)), so I want to clear up that issue from the start by grabbing the `region_name` from a known bucket:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
region = s3.meta.client.get_bucket_location(Bucket='some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods')['LocationConstraint']
#set region in resource
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',region_name=region)
```

To see all the buckets at the top level:

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

If we want to see the contents of 'some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods':

```
x = s3.Bucket('some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods')
for item in x.objects.all():
    print item
```

The following should also provide info:

```
s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket='some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods')
s3.meta.client.get_bucket_acl(Bucket='some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods')
```

To upload some test file to an appropriate bucket:

```
with open ('~/someFile.pdf', 'rb') as data:
    s3.meta.client.put_object(Bucket='some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods',Key='s3SubDir1/s3SubDir2/someTestFile1.pdf', Body=data)


with open ('~/someFile.pdf', 'rb') as data:
    s3.Bucket('some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods').put_object(Key='s3SubDir1/s3SubDir2/someTestFile2.pdf', Body=data)
```

**Question:

 1. How can we view the contents of the path `some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods/s3SubDir1/s3SubDir2/`?**

I started down this road:

```
x = s3.Bucket('some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods')
for item in x.objects.all():
    for thing in item.objects.all():
        print thing
```

ERROR:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-bc4079ea1f49> in <module>()
      1 x = s3.Bucket('some.topLevel.BucketPath.withPeriods')
      2 for item in x.objects.all():
----> 3     for thing in item.objects.all():
      4         print thing

AttributeError: 's3.ObjectSummary' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh whoops - I thought you were facing the problem of using buckets with periods in the name (which is an actual problem). Retracting my comment. Also, S3 doesn't have the concept of 'sub buckets'  (buckets are just flat lists of key names, essentially). It _sounds_ like you really just want to get a list of files without the 'virtual pathing' of `/subdir1/subdir2/etc/etc/etc`?

Comment: I'd basically like to be able to have some sort of `$ ls` capability at any level of a path. Thanks for considering the question. I'll retract my former comment as well.

Comment: I voted to reopen this because the question is not related to the duplicate, and asks a different question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the file list in one bucket:

```
file_list = []
for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    # you can also get what type file you want
    if file.key.endswith('.docx'):
         file_list.append(file.key)
```

returned result file_list is all files that contains in this S3.