# boto3 upload file to s3 error when bucket name has period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am coding a python script to upload file to s3 with boto3. My bucket name is like 'my.bucket', and I get the connect time out error.

Here is the error code.

```
    botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:        
    HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com', port=443):      
    Max retries exceeded with url: /pandarental.com/app.css (Caused by 
    ConnectTimeoutError(<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 
    0x108ff6350>, 'Connection to s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com timed out.         
    (connect timeout=60)'))
```

I tried to change the bucket name to 'mybucket' and it worked!
I have no idea what's wrong in it， boto3 doesn't support bucket name with period?

Here is my code:

```
    class StorageManage():
    def __init__(self, bucket_name):
      s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
      self.bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

    def putObject(self, file_name, key, type):
      try:
        t = content_type.get(type,{})
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as data:
            new_object = self.bucket.put_object(Key=key, Body=data, 
                ACL=t.get('ACL',''), 
                ContentType=t.get('ContentType',''), 
                CacheControl=t.get('CacheControl',''),
                ContentEncoding=t.get('ContentEncoding',''))

        print 'upload file %s success' % new_object.key 
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        print e
    return None
```

btw, I found two issues: [this one](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836) and [this one](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/334), said that config address_style=path in ~/.aws/config can work. I tried but failed.

Comment: I have found the reason for this error. In the source code of botocore/utils.py, it said that 'Even though "." characters are perfectly valid in this DNS naming scheme, we are going to punt on any name containing a "." character because these will cause SSL cert validationproblems if we try to use virtual-hosting style addressing.' But still have no idea to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access keys from buckets with periods (.) in their names using boto3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534410/how-to-access-keys-from-buckets-with-periods-in-their-names-using-boto3)

Comment: I tired that way but didn't work, also getting the `ConnectTimeoutError`. I never got the `ClientError PermanentRedirect`. Besides, I also tried aws cli, like `aws s3 ls s3://my.bucket`, but it still doesn't work when bucket name has '.' . I started to think about DNS problem, but I can access the file in browser like `my.bucket.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/app.css.` It's so strange.